# printing values vector f[0]

Tags: c++

Assuming I have a fraction class and i do want to keep them in the vector
I did create a fraction vector

However, I don't know how to read the value inside the vector, by reading I mean printing the value out

It turns out `f[0]` will print out the address of fraction instead of the data of fraction

```
void main()
{
    fraction fr(2,5);
    vector<fraction*> f;
    f.push_back(&fr);
    cout<<f[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't store pointers. And `main` must return an `int`, not `void`.

Comment: You don't have a "fraction vector". You have a vector of pointers to fraction.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing *pointers to `fraction`* in your vector: `vector<fraction*>`.

```
cout << f[0]->numerator << "/" << f[0]->denominator << endl;
```

Comment: and is it possible to use the vector<fraction*>:: iterator i; ? to access each of the value ?

Comment: @user2659072, Why make it harder than it has to be? Store the actual objects and there's no extra work involved.

Comment: @chris Sorry, just being a C programmer :-P

Answer (score 0):

To print the data use  `cout<<*(f[0])<<endl;` instead of  `cout<<f[0]<<endl;`

**Reason:** As you are storing only pointers of type fraction in f, f[0] gives you a pointer inorder to get a value, just dereference it using * operator.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are producing a vector consisting of the adresses to fraction types

If you really want to store pointer objects the easiest way to get value stored at f[0] would be *f[0], because f[0] is a pointer, pointing to your fraction class object

EDIT: (becaus of your comment question)
I'd like to explain you your program:

```
void main()
{
    fraction fr(2,5);
    vector<fraction*> f; // define a vector-object storing fraction-class pointers
    f.push_back(&fr); // adding the address of fr
    cout<<f[0]<<endl; // printing out the address of fr which was previously stored
}
```

If you restart this programm several times, it might possibly give you different output. You will always get the address, where fr is stored at, but this address can differ if restarting the programm (because of other programms on your pc needing memory space meanwhile , etc.)

If you write a program like:

```
void main()
{
    fraction fr(2,5);
    vector<fraction*> f;
    f.push_back(&fr);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) cout<<f[0]<<endl;
}
```

This programm will give you 10 times the same output, always the address of fr and always the same because the memory space where fr is allocated stays the same for the whole program flow. (If you reexecute it it will possibly give you 10 times a different adress, but all 10 will be the same)

If you like to get the value of fr you have at least two possible options:

```
void main()
{
    fraction fr(2,5);
    vector<fraction> f;  // no "*" so there is no pointer allocated
    f.push_back(fr); // no "&" so there is just the object fr stored, not its address
    cout<<f[0]<<endl;
}
```

Second option:

```
void main()
{
    fraction fr(2,5);
    vector<fraction*> f;  // pointer allocated
    f.push_back(&fr); // address of fr stored
    cout<<*f[0]<<endl; // the object at the address f[0] is printed out because of "*"
}
```

I would also recommend you to use the Memberfunction f.at() of vectors, because it returns an Error if you try to address an index out of the "array/vector" range.

I hope that solves your problems with that. If not, just ask again in the comments ;)

Comment: @user2659072, What should it print? You need to overload `operator<<` to tell it.

Comment: however why it always print the same value ??

Comment: even if I print the f[0] it will give me the same address again and again. should i use iterator ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "always the same"... if you always hit cout << f[0] << endl; it will give you always the address of this variable, if you restart your programm and the only thing it does is cout << f[0] << endl; then the variable might possibly stored at a different place and thus have a differnt output... was that what you were meaning?